# Ruby: Unable to access global variable, not starting with $

Tags: ruby

Normally every global variable in ruby ​​should start with a $. Are these parameters "param_string" and "param_array" also global variables or something else?

```
require 'json'
require 'fileutils'

param_string=String.new
param_array=Array.new

# global variable
$tester="hello"

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: staging.rb [options]"
  opts.on("-s","--string TEST") do |test|
    puts "test string #{test}"
    param_string << test
  end
end.parse!

def string_funktion()
  puts $tester      
  # working as expected

  puts "show my string #{param_string}"
  # error: undefined local variable 
end
```

Attempting to access one of these parameters "param_string" or "param_array" within a function and get the error message that the parameter is not defined. If I do the same with the variable $tester, the access works as desired.

What do I have to change for accessing the parameters "param_string" or "param_array" within a function?

EDIT:

Are there reasons or best practices for globally defined variables without naming $?

Comment: put a `$` in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally every global variable in ruby ​​should start with a $.

This is wrong. This has nothing to do with "should".

If it starts with a `$`, then it is a global variable. If it doesn't, then it is not a global variable.

> Are these parameters "param_string" and "param_array" also global variables or something else?

Variables that start with a lowercase letter are *local variables*. Local variables are called "local" variables, because they are local to the scope they are defined in. In this case, they are defined in the script body, so they are local to the script body.

There are 4 different scopes in Ruby:

- Script
- Module / Class definition
- Method definition
- Block / lambda literal

Block scopes are special, because they can be *closures* and are *nested*.

> Attempting to access one of these parameters "param_string" or "param_array" within a function and get the error message that the parameter is not defined. If I do the same with the variable $tester, the access works as desired.

[Note: this is not a function, it is a method. Ruby doesn't have functions.]

`param_string` and `param_array` are *local variables*, which you can see because they start with a lowercase letter. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, in this case the script scope. Therefore, they are not defined in the method.

`$tester` is a *global variable*, which you can see because it starts with a `$` sign. Global variables are, as the name implies, global. Therefore, it can be accessed everywhere. (Note that there are some builtin "magic" global variables like `$!` or `$1`…`$9` that behave slightly differently. As a beginner, it is probably easiest to ignore those slight differences for now.)

> What do I have to change for accessing the parameters "param_string" or "param_array" within a function?

You could make them global variables, but in general, global variables should be avoided. (Not just in Ruby.)

What the best design in your case would be is hard to tell from the code you provided. You could pass them into the method as arguments, but it is also possible that your design is missing an object or two.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to pass the local variables to the function as parameters.

```
def string_funktion(param_string, param_array)
```